# Trying to create a Bayesian-style formula for weighing arguments that have a certain chance of "establishing" a hypothesis

Tags: bayesian

The core problem I'm having is that I have a set of independent probabilities which represent the chance that a certain hypothesis is true according different methods (the details of which aren't important here). How do I factor these in together so that every probability greater than 0.5 increases the overall posterior probability of the hypothesis and each one less than 0.5 decreases it, without running into the problem of generating posterior probabilities greater than one?

This is for a personal project of mine, and I've only taken a few college courses on statistics so I'm kind of out of my depth. My initial approach was to take an average of each of the probabilities, and then multiply it by the prior probability of the hypothesis in question, but that... doesn't really work, because any probability in the sum that's less than 100% will just make the total smaller.

I know this is a really strange application of statistics, but does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any reason to believe each of the probabilities is more likely to be correct than the others, I think a simple average would work. This would be similar to how a random forest classifier works - a bunch of (hopefully not too correlated) probabilities that an instance belongs to a class, averaged over the group of probabilities.